# Unresolved references in new Flutter Project within Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

When creating a new Flutter Project in Android Studio I get a series of unresolved references immediately in both MainActivity.kt and GeneratePlouginRegistrant as below.

[image]

If I then open the the android module in AS separately, these references seem to be resolved (**EDIT:** although not if I return to the original) however I then get the following. (My Android Gradle Plugin currently 3.5.3 and Gradle Version 5.6.2).

```
ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'implementation()'
Possible causes:
The project 'android' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
Upgrade plugin to version 3.5.3 and sync project

The project 'android' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin
```

and this...

```
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.wrapException(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:80)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:73)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$600(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:53)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject$1.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:109)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:189)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withProjectLock(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:227)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:221)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:187)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:693)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:141)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:36)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:62)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(DefaultProjectsPreparer.java:55)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperatingFiringProjectsPreparer$ConfigureBuild.run(BuildOperatingFiringProjectsPreparer.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperatingFiringProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildOperatingFiringProjectsPreparer.java:40)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.prepareProjects(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:198)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doClassicBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:138)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:126)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:60)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:85)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:189)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:57)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:63)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:68)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:27)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$2.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:227)
    at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:77)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:232)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:69)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.execute(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:66)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.execute(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:63)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:49)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:63)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor$1.run(BuildScriptProcessor.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:201)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:187)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:35)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject$1.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:107)
    ... 110 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.methodMissingException(AbstractDynamicObject.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.ConfigureDelegate.invokeMethod(ConfigureDelegate.java:86)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeOnDelegationObjects(ClosureMetaClass.java:398)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:338)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:168)
    at build_9446wglxy75nh6irqvw8yfcli$_run_closure5.doCall(D:\Peeps\Documents\PL_Consulting\App_Development\Flutter\delete\delete\android\build.gradle:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:104)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:326)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:264)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:427)
    at org.gradle.util.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:71)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:154)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:105)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.dependencies(DefaultProject.java:1192)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor345.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:104)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:326)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:479)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:191)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.CompositeDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.java:33)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript$ScriptDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BasicScript.java:134)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.invokeMethod(AbstractDynamicObject.java:162)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.invokeMethod(BasicScript.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:74)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:168)
    at build_9446wglxy75nh6irqvw8yfcli.run(D:\Peeps\Documents\PL_Consulting\App_Development\Flutter\delete\delete\android\build.gradle:33)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:91)
    ... 133 more
```

FLutter Doctor

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.476], locale en-AU)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.8 at D:\...
    • Framework revision 0b8abb4724 (12 days ago), 2020-02-11 11:44:36 -0800
    • Engine revision e1e6ced81d
    • Dart version 2.7.0


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\...
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 43.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Redmi 6 • 672382f37d26 • android-arm • Android 8.1.0 (API 27)

• No issues found!
```

I wonder if these are issues that need to be resolved?

Comment: Does the Flutter app run fine?

Comment: Its a good question. I was running some tests on a plugin that was failing at the MainActivty.kt where the NonNull in configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) was unresolved. When I removed the statement it did run fine so I was trying to rule out the unresolved reference issue before I conclude that the plugin was the reason. I will run some other code to answer better.

Comment: Hmmn...Maybe that's all there is to it @GazihanAlankus. I'm not seeing any issues running a complex app. So is the simple answer to just ignore labelled AS errors in flutter outside your code?!

Comment: Probably so. I got used to ignoring highlights related to Android code.

Answer (score 0):

If the Flutter app works fine when run on Android, then the errors can be ignored. You can run `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get` to refresh the lint checks on the Flutter project.

To access the Android project with proper lint check, it's better to open it via **Tools > Flutter > Open Android module in Android Studio**